# Capturing two different lines using regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I want to capture two lines in one variable, like this is my input:

`Rose                          0                        82`
**`ABC                           0                        0`**
`ABC (Backup)                  0                        0`
**`ABC XYZ                       637                      2021`**
`ABC XYZ (Backup)              0                        0`
`ABC EXYZ                      0                        0`

I Want to capture the lines which are in bold.

I tried this code:

```
var = re.search("ABC\s+\d+\s+ .*\n(.*)\nABC XYZ .*",file_name)
```

but it is giving me output like this:

```
ABC                           0                        0
ABC (Backup)                  0                        0
ABC XYZ                       637                      2021
```

and my expected output is this:

```
ABC                           0                        0
ABC XYZ                       637                      2021
```

Can someone please suggest what modification is needed.

Comment: I posted the [working answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58026731/3832970).

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
re.search("^(ABC[ \t]+\d+[ \t].*\n).*\n(ABC[ \t]+XYZ[ \t].*)",s, re.MULTILINE)
```

The regex will find the match you need and capture 2 lines into separate *capturing groups*. Then, check if there was a match and, if yes, join the two capturing group values.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/0wrlUP)

```
import re
s="""Rose                          0                        82
ABC                           0                        0
ABC (Backup)                  0                        0
ABC XYZ                       637                      2021
ABC XYZ (Backup)              0                        0
ABC EXYZ                      0                        0"""

v = re.search("^(ABC[ \t]+\d+[ \t].*\n).*\n(ABC[ \t]+XYZ[ \t].*)",s, re.MULTILINE)
if v:
    print("{}{}".format(v.group(1), v.group(2)))
```

Output:

```
ABC                           0                        0
ABC XYZ                       637                      2021
```

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of a line (due to `re.MULTILINE`)
- `(ABC[ \t]+\d+[ \t].*\n)` - Capturing group 1: `ABC`, 1+ spaces or tabs, 1+ digits, a space or tab and then the rest of the line with the newline
- `.*\n` - whole next line
- `(ABC[ \t]+XYZ[ \t].*)` -  - Capturing group 2: `ABC`, 1+ spaces or tabs, `XYZ`, a space or tab and then the rest of the line.

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of the "^" and the "$" to catch the start and end of a line.

`^\*\*.*\*\*`

This will give you 2 matches to iterate through. All the matches represent blod lines, qualified by the two * in the beginning end end of a line.

Comment: There are no asterisks in the real text. OP tried to bold the text (*I Want to capture the lines which are in bold.*), but failed to format the question correctly.

Comment: I posted [the working solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58026731/3832970).

Answer (score 0):

If the syntax includes a comment start as two stars than you can use this (but it will not cut two comments, if they are in one line).

```
^[\*]{2}(.*)[\*]{2}
```

If you want to find any comment with the form of `**comment**` use this

```
[\*]{2}[^\*]+[\*]{2}
```

Comment: There are no asterisks in the real text. OP tried to bold the text (*I Want to capture the lines which are in bold.*), but failed to format the question correctly. Besides, if there had been asterisks OP current output would have been different.

Comment: Ok thanks. So if he only wants the part between the stars then he can use `res = re.findall(r"[\*]{2}[^\*]+[\*]{2}",myString)`to find all comments and 
`res = [elem.replace("**","") for elem in res]` to cut out the stars. Is this what you meant?

Comment: No, there are no asterisks.

Comment: yes there are no **. I tried it to bold but failed to format. @lesem

Comment: I posted [the working solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58026731/3832970).